# Filter Through Certain Object in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a personObject with a `NSString`, `UIImage`, and a `BOOL` property. I want to create a Predicate that filters through just the `NSString`

```
personObject *person1 = [[personObject alloc]initWithName:@"John Smith" Photo:nil Invited:false];
personObject *person2 = [[personObject alloc]initWithName:@"Peter Smith" Photo:nil Invited:false];
personObject *person3 = [[personObject alloc]initWithName:@"Paul Smith" Photo:nil Invited:false];

[self.peopleArray addObject:person1];
[self.peopleArray addObject:person2];
[self.peopleArray addObject:person3];

- (void) filterContententForSearchText: (NSString *) searchText scope:(NSString *) scope{
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
self.searchArray = [self.peopleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

}

People array contains the personObjects.

Comment: `@"self.stringNameProperty beginswith[c] %@"` ?

Comment: Yes-   reason: '-[personObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109664810'

Comment: and   reason: '-[personObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109512760'   if I use personName begins with[c] %@

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings))block
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the `name` property, and use `contains` if you want to search it as a substring, see this example:

Class PersonObject:

```
@interface PersonObject : NSObject
{
    NSString* name;
    UIImage* img;
    BOOL invited;
}
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name Photo:(UIImage*)img Invited:(BOOL)invited;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *img;
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isInvited) BOOL invited;
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "PersonObject.h"

@implementation PersonObject

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)n Photo:(UIImage*)im Invited:(BOOL)i{
    if(self = [super init]){
        _name=n;
        _img=im;
        _invited=i;
    }
    return self;
    }

@end
```

Code:

```
PersonObject *person1 = [[PersonObject alloc]initWithName:@"John Smith" Photo:nil Invited:false];
PersonObject *person2 = [[PersonObject alloc]initWithName:@"Peter Smith" Photo:nil Invited:false];
PersonObject *person3 = [[PersonObject alloc]initWithName:@"Paul Smith" Photo:nil Invited:false];

[self.peopleArray addObject:person1];
[self.peopleArray addObject:person2];
[self.peopleArray addObject:person3];


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@", @"Smith"];
self.searchArray = [self.peopleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"results: %@", self.searchArray);
```

It outputs:

```
2014-09-22 14:57:31.010 asf[27731:2455623] results: (
"<personObject: 0x7ffdbe301050>",
"<personObject: 0x7ffdbe3010c0>",
"<personObject: 0x7ffdbe3010f0>"
)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this is for a search bar so I need to use beginswith

Comment: of course, this was just a suggestion of course you could, anyway the main problem was you were not using the key "name" for filtering the array.

Comment: yea thats not working. The property name is personName and the error message I get is----reason: '-[personObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1095395e0'

Comment: please check my code, I added the PersonObject class, this way it works because I tested. You might want to start from there, please note that in my case the property is called `name` in yours is `personName`.